# 16.04 Kernel upgrade ends with E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Tags: apt, kernel, dpkg

I've tried all I can from other solutions, but can't seem to remove any kernels or upgrade to new ones. Anyone have a clue?

I Have tried:

> sudo dpkg -l linux-* | awk '/^ii/{ print $2}' | grep -v -e `uname -r | cut -f1,2 -d"-"` | grep -e [0-9] | xargs sudo apt-get -y purge

And any variation of this:

> sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

Output attached. (First id failure output, then cat /etc/default/grub, then grub config showing all the kernels)[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: please edit your question and add the output of 'cat /etc/default/grub'

Comment: It comes out unformatted.

Comment: Try this: `sudo apt install --reinstall linux-image-4.4.0-21-generic`, then `sudo apt remove linux-image-4.4.0-21-generic`. If that works, remove the other kernels one by one in the same way.

Comment: Same output, but thank you.